# Why there are two R2 for calculation between predicted and actual values?

Tags: excel, linear-regression, coefficient-of-determination

I am a little bit confused about the exact formula behind R2. the first one is this formula:
[image]

and we have also this formula

[image]

could you please explain me what are the difference? when I put my predicted, and actual values in excell sheets, the second formula give me the similar results to the R2 that I obtain from trendline in excel.

Comment: You need to add some data (as markdown table) and the Excel formulas you use. Also explain what direction you need the answer to be in. They're different equations, but what difference you need explained?

Comment: Notice is not the same *R2* than just *r* (I guess it's Pearson correlation coefficient). If the relation between X and Y is linear, yes, *R2* is the square of *r* but i the relation between X and Y is not linear, then not.